# How to determine sound recording source

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, audio, audio-recording

While recording a sound using my iPad app, how can I know if the source of the sound is from the built-in microphone or headphone microphone?

Additional information: iOS ver 4.2 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to determine this is to poll the hardware and query the current audio route.

Use the [AudioSessionGetProperty](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) object to get back the route of the audio.

This [example by @TPoschel](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/9982-play-record-same-time.html) should set you on the right track.

```
- (void)playSound:(id) sender
{
    if(player){

        CFStringRef route;
        UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
        AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &route);

        if((route == NULL) || (CFStringGetLength(route) == 0)){
            // Silent Mode
            NSLog(@"AudioRoute: SILENT");
        } else {
            NSString* routeStr = (NSString*)route;
            NSLog(@"AudioRoute: %@", routeStr);

            /* Known values of route:
             * "Headset"
             * "Headphone"
             * "Speaker"
             * "SpeakerAndMicrophone"
             * "HeadphonesAndMicrophone"
             * "HeadsetInOut"
             * "ReceiverAndMicrophone"
             * "Lineout"
             */

            NSRange headphoneRange = [routeStr rangeOfString : @"Headphone"];
            NSRange headsetRange = [routeStr rangeOfString : @"Headset"];
            NSRange receiverRange = [routeStr rangeOfString : @"Receiver"];
            NSRange speakerRange = [routeStr rangeOfString : @"Speaker"];
            NSRange lineoutRange = [routeStr rangeOfString : @"Lineout"];

            if (headphoneRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                // Don't change the route if the headphone is plugged in.
            } else if(headsetRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                // Don't change the route if the headset is plugged in.
            } else if (receiverRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                // Change to play on the speaker
                UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
                AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
            } else if (speakerRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                // Don't change the route if the speaker is currently playing.
            } else if (lineoutRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                // Don't change the route if the lineout is plugged in.
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Unknown audio route.");
            }
        }

        [player play];
    }
}
```